# Join to table-valued function in MSSQL 2000?

Tags: sql, function

I have a table with a whole name.  I have a function that receives said name, parses it, and returns a table with first, middle, last, and suffix.  I have a `bad` (edit: was "hyper-conservative") DBA who won't upgrade the dev server to the same version as the production one so I can't just use APPLY and be done with it:

```
insert into blah (name, firstName, middleName, lastName, suffix)
select a.name, b.firstName, b.middleName, b.lastName, b.suffix
from employees a CROSS APPLY dbo.parseName(a.name) b
```

Please help, or I will be forced to write code like this:

```
insert into blah (name, firstName, middleName, lastName, suffix)
select 
    name, dbo.getNamePart(name, 'f') as firstName, 
    dbo.getNamePart(name, 'm') as middleName, 
    dbo.getNamePart(name, 'l') as lastName, 
    dbo.getNamePart(name, 's') as suffix 
from employees r
```

Comment: Why not post what your 2005 syntax would look like? That may get more responses.

Comment: Dev should match Production. Period.

Comment: A hyper-conservative DBA would upgrade dev first...

Comment: How was it developed in the first place to use APPLY in production?

Comment: It wasn't.  The previous team was happy with the second code snippet (calling getNamePart over and over), and I'm trying to improve on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be able to join to the UDF if it wasn't processing data from the other table.  That is, you can write this:

```
select name, b.EXPANSION
  from employees a
  join dbo.parseName('John Smith') b
    on a.CODE = b.CODE
```

but only because myFunc isn't referencing any fields in tb1.  That's what APPLY was created for.

The way I see it, you have three options:

1. Your insert statement with one function reference per field
2. A cursor over the result set, so the function can be called one row at a time
3. Find a way to get the dev environment in sync with production, up to and including getting a better DBA.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like "dev" and "live" use different versions? Not using the same product on your dev/production servers is a **liability**. A "conservative" DBA should want them to match...

I'm unclear - are you *writing* the function that "returns a table with first, middle, last, and suffix", or *consuming* it. If you are *consuming* it, you should just be able to `SELECT` from the UDF, or `JOIN` to it, etc. IIRC, you just alias the UDF as you would a table:

```
...
from dbo.myTableUdf(...) x
inner join SomeTable y on x.id = y.id
```

Comment: There was originally something other than 'conservative' there but it was inappropriate and I changed it. The table-valued function takes one of the fields from the table as an argument:  `select * from parseName(b.name) a inner join nameTable b on a.name = b.wholeName` Does not work.

Comment: Are you **sure** that is a table valued function? Sounds more like a scalar function to me...

Comment: I've added another code snipped to my question which I hope will clarify this.